How do i change the CurrentItem in a CarouselView?
I am fairly new to MAUI Apps and what i have is a CarouselView bound to a collection of students. Everything is working fine, however I have an issue which appears to be widespread - I have a Next and Previous button which I want to use to navigate from one item in the carousel to the next.
The Previous button works fine, however the Next button doesn't behave as expected. If I have, for example, 3 students in my collection, I cannot smoothly navigate from Student 1 (position 0) to Student 2 (position 1).
I have to click the next button twice and it's only on the 3rd click that it finally moves to student 2. It keeps resetting back to student 1. I monitored the behavior in Debug mode and I can see that the current Item in the preview does indeed change when I debug the NextButton_Clicked method, but as soon as the debug exits the method, the CurrentItem resets back to student 1 (position 0). As I mentioned, my Students collection is working fine and the data is as expected and I do not have any other (visible) triggers that may be overriding the CurrentItem change. For reference, my methods in the code-behind are below:
private void NextButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (StudentCarousel.ItemsSource is IList<Student> students)
    {
        int studentCount = students.Count;
        int nextPosition = (CurrentPosition + 1) % studentCount;

        Debug.WriteLine($"NextButton_Clicked: Setting Position to {nextPosition}");

        // Update Position before CurrentItem
        CurrentPosition = nextPosition;
        StudentCarousel_CurrentItem = students[nextPosition];

    }
}

private void StudentCarousel_PositionChanged(object sender, PositionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"PositionChanged Event: New Position = {e.CurrentPosition}");
}

private void CarouselView_CurrentItemChanged(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.CurrentItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CurrentItem is Student currentStudent)
    {
        CurrentItem = currentStudent;
    }
}

I also have the code below:
public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Student>();

private int _currentPosition;

public int CurrentPosition
{
    get => _currentPosition;
    set
    {
        if (_currentPosition != value)
        {
            _currentPosition = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentPosition));
            Debug.WriteLine($"CurrentPosition set to: {_currentPosition}");
        }
    }
}

private Student _studentCarousel_CurrentItem;

public Student StudentCarousel_CurrentItem
{
    get => _studentCarousel_CurrentItem;
    set
    {
        if (_studentCarousel_CurrentItem != value)
        {
            _studentCarousel_CurrentItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StudentCarousel_CurrentItem));
        }
    }
}

Below is the .xaml code:
     <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="5" BorderColor="Gray" BackgroundColor="White" HasShadow="True" HeightRequest="250" WidthRequest="300"
HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
         <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="10">
             <!-- CarouselView -->
             <RefreshView>
                 <CarouselView x:Name="StudentCarousel" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" Loop="True"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               HeightRequest="250" WidthRequest="300" IndicatorView="CarouselIndicator"  IsScrollAnimated="True" CurrentItem="{Binding StudentCarousel_CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay}" CurrentItemChanged="CarouselView_CurrentItemChanged" Position="{Binding CurrentPosition, Mode=TwoWay}" PositionChanged="StudentCarousel_PositionChanged" >
                     <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                             <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="5" ColumnSpacing="10" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                     <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                     <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                     <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                     <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                     <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                     <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                 <!-- Image -->
                                 <Image Source="student_icon.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                                 <!-- Label: Student Info -->
                                 <Label Text="Student Info" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />

                                 <!-- Label: Full Name -->
                                 <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                     <Label.FormattedText>
                                         <FormattedString>
                                             <Span Text="FullName: " FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                             <Span Text="{Binding FullNameWithMiddleName}" />
                                         </FormattedString>
                                     </Label.FormattedText>
                                 </Label>
                             </Grid>
                         </DataTemplate>
                     </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                 </CarouselView>
             </RefreshView>
             <!-- Navigation Buttons -->
             <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                 <Button x:Name="PreviousButton" Text="Previous" Clicked="PreviousButton_Clicked" />
                 <Button x:Name="NextButton" Text="Next" Clicked="NextButton_Clicked" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
             </StackLayout>
         </StackLayout>
     </Frame>

I am completely stuck and not sure where I am going wrong. Any advice is appreciated.

you have multiple bound properties and event handlers that are fighting against one another.  Don't update both Position and CurrentItem, just pick one.  And be sure your changed handlers aren't causing a cascade of recursive events.

@Jason than you for the response - are you able to provide an example of the code?

Here is my solution.
I remove the currentItem and change it to Student_CurrentItem.
private void CarouselView_CurrentItemChanged(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.CurrentItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CurrentItem is Student currentStudent)
    {
        Student_CurrentItem = currentStudent;
    }
}

